# Cannot Run a Python Script at Boot

Tags: python, boot

I am at wits-end and am close to giving up on this... All I want to do is run a python script at bootup with the Raspberry Pi, I will outline the few things that i've tried thus far:

1. [Running the script from /etc/Profile.](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/02/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-raspberry-pi-boot/) I used the exact script that the guy posted in his example and absolutely nothing happened. Just booted up to the normal desktop, did not open up a terminal or anything.
2. [Running the script via CRON.](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/07/running-a-python-script-at-boot-using-cron/) Tried this as well and got the same results as number one.

What on earth are some possible things that could be wrong here? Some details I can provide are that somebody else monkeyed with the OS  installed on the card before I started working with it, so is it possible that I'm being *prevented* from running anything at startup somehow?

I am running an "LXDE" environment, if that means anything to anyone?

Update:

I did everything in the following article and I ALMOST got it working.

[LXTerminal from LXDE desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=65607)

The terminal showed up but my script did not run. The following is my script:

```
@/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.pi
```

Nothing shows up in the terminal, not even the current user name (usually pi@raspberrypi).

Comment: If you are going to script a secret you will not get any answers which do not repeat all the similar questions on this site,

Comment: @Milliways See my update, I've added the script text. It's just one line where I launch python and have it execute the `myscript.py` from my link posted as item #1. Please let me know anything else I can add to help make the question as clear and specific as possible!!

Comment: Why the leading `@` character? Remove that.

Comment: @SiKing Thanks, I will try that! Check out the link I posted in my update, that guy uses an @ character and to be honest I just copied his code verbatim. Sorry, I am probably just another person that doesn't put any thought it and rushes through things.

Comment: "person that doesn't put any thought it and rushes through things" is not good! 9 times out of 10 it will not work, and the 1 time you will not understand why and will just become "magic".

Comment: @SiKing Well, I did slow down read through it and figure out where I went wrong. After following through the tutorial posted by *androidian* on the Raspberry Pi forums, I forgot to set the script to executable.

Answer (score 1):

You failed to understand the instructions.

> I used the exact script that the guy posted in his example and absolutely nothing happened. Just booted up to the normal desktop, did not open up a terminal or anything.

In the example, the author was **not** using a graphical environment. His Pi was setup to only boot to a command prompt! If you read through the script, it never attempts to launch a command window, it only outputs to the **current** window it is run in.

Assuming you followed the rest of the instructions, once your Pi boots to the graphical interface (LXDE in your case), open a command terminal (which will execute the startup `/etc/profile` script), and you should see the output, as per the author's comment:

> Due to the technique we’ve used the script is run whenever the Pi user logs in. This means if you create other terminal sessions (via SSH for example) the script will run each time.

Comment: Ok, please check out my update.

Comment: I am starting to understand trying it in the LXDE environment.

Comment: All though I have yet to get this working, I do recognize that difference between what I am doing and what the tutorial does. That tutorial was not running through a graphical environment.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand that the solutions you have researched are not the same thing!

`/etc/profile` is, as it says on top

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
```

meaning that it is the first thing that runs when someone starts a (Bourne compatible) shell. This means

1. It will *not* run on boot and will *not* run until someone starts a shell
2. It will run *every* time someone starts a new shell

If you want your script to run *once* at *boot*, then `profile` is the wrong solution.

You want to research the manual page of `crontab`, and of `crontab` in section
5. `crontab` lets you install a rules table for the `cron`-deamon. In section 5 you can read about how to create such a table. Run

```
man crontab
```

and read it, and then run

```
man 5 crontab
```

and read that as well.

When done, you can execute

```
sudo crontab -e
```

to edit the superuser cron rules table of your computer. You probably want to add the line

```
@reboot    '/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.pi'
```

at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian honours `/etc/rc.local`, so run your script from there (but above the line with `exit 0` ). Any output will go directly to stdout, so if you want to keep it, redirect it to a file.

Edit: This runs in a different (root) context, and will not work for X programs - though you can put something like 
`#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0 ; sleep 60 ; myXProgram >/dev/null 2>&1 &` in a script, and call it thus: `myScript.sh &` from rc.local. Remember to authorize local X connections elsewhere with `xhost +local`.